# Question on the convergence $⨍_{\{f(x,y+s)>0\}} \to ⨍_{\{f(x,s)>0\}}$ as $y\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be a continuous function in both variables, i.e  $f \in C(U \times [0,M])$ for some $M< \infty$ and $U$ compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$

> **QUESTION:** If $\vert \{f(x,s)>0\} \vert <\infty$, is continuity in time sufficient in order to claim the following convergence:  $⨍_{\{f(x,y+s)>0\}} \to ⨍_{\{f(x,s)>0\}}$ as
>   $y\to 0$

where $⨍$ denotes the average integral over the corresponding sets.

I believe that the answer is positive. However, since the average integral operator is involved, I 'm getting a bit puzzled about how trivial my question is.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $\{f(x,y)>0\}$ of finite measure? Otherwise I wonder how you define the average.

Comment: @amsmath yes, it is. I will add it

Comment: @amsmath thanks. stupid typo

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{|A|}\int_A\,dx = 1$. What do you mean by the average integral? Please write it out.

Comment: @amsmath For the average integral I use the same definition as you do... So, the convergence is trivial?

Comment: Well, if $⨍_{\{f(x,y+s)>0\}}$ means $\frac{1}{|\{f(x,y+s)>0\}|}\int_{\{f(x,y+s)>0\}}1\,dt\,dr$, then it's just $1$. Same for the other.